# Why is the play button not working on the title screen of my game?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to open up a game demo from my class to see what it looks like, but after opening up the project in Unity, the title screen doesn't work correctly. When I try to click the "Play" button, the game doesn't start.

I'm not sure what's going on because everything was working when the instructor did the demo of this in class and all the files that I downloaded are the same. I also double checked the console messages and no error/warning messages pop up. Below is a screenshot of what I see, as well as a link to the project itself if you'd like to try it out on your own. Thanks in advance!

Here is a link to the project if you want to try it out yourself: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ekXt948b612dmyT1AZReUOuzh2XbnSDG/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the console window when you click play or start running the game?

Comment: Hm, I believe it just comes up with the debugging log statements; it says: [Singleton] Using instance already created: Manager
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Singleton`1:get_Instance() (at Assets/Scripts/Singleton.cs:56)
PlayerControl:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerControl.cs:69) @Eddge

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Most users aren't going to download a project or read through source code located elsewhere. While it is possible that someone may be able to troubleshoot based solely on the provided description, it might help if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that recreates the problem.

Comment: Is the event onclick of the button properly assigned?

Comment: Did your teacher demo with a touch screen? I notice that's in a mobile resolution, and it's possible the app was coded only for touch screen input. I believe unity can emulate a touch screen, it's worth looking into. But that might be your issue.